# Does THROW statement includes ROLLBACK?

Tags: triggers, sql-server-2012, throw

I am currently learning SQL Server 2012 and this is my trigger on the `ANIMALS` table that doesn't allow insert of more than 3 animals of the same type.

Probably there are better solutions to implement this but I am curious about `THROW` and `ROLLBACK` statement.

Question is: does `THROW` include a `ROLLBACK` and is it necessary (or which is better) to use both statements? I tried with them both and separate, trigger always work...

```
create trigger TRI_ANIMALS 
on ANIMALS
after insert
as
begin
    declare @NewAnimalId int

    select @NewAnimalId = inserted.FK_ANIMAL_TYPE 
    from inserted

    if (select count(*) from ANIMALS
        where @NewAnimalId = ANIMALS.FK_ANIMAL_TYPE) > 4
    begin;
        throw 50002, 'There are already 3 animals of the same type', 1;
        rollback;
    end;
end
go

/* test */
insert into ANIMALS(NAME, FK_ANIMAL_TYPE) values('Bono', 2);
insert into ANIMALS(NAME, FK_ANIMAL_TYPE) values('Cesar', 2);
insert into ANIMALS(NAME, FK_ANIMAL_TYPE) values('Ron', 2);
/* this must not be inserted */
insert into ANIMALS(NAME, FK_ANIMAL_TYPE) values('Ares', 2);
```

Comment: Your trigger is broken - it assumes `inserted` contains exactly one row. `inserted` can contain 0, 1 or *multiple* rows.

Comment: And to answer, NO, THROW doesn't apply a ROLLBACK.